# Why does std::map have a find member function?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

A colleague and I were discussing the relative merits of member vs. non-member functions.  A question arose: why does `std::map` have a `find` member function.

My answer was that although you can use `std::find` on maps, you must search for the key-value pair, or use find_if and e.g. a lambda.  However, this is linear and `map.find` offers a search by key in better than linear time.  I ended with the assertion that if it could have been a non-member, then it would have been! (Although, std::string suggests that I might have been somewhat hasty in my generalization).

My colleague pointed out that it would be possible to implement `find` the same way as a non-member function using `map.lower_bound`.

Is there a rationale for `map.find` having been made a member?

Comment: Clarification requested: You're still asking about a three-argument free function `std::find(map::iterator begin, map::iterator end, key)` ? Because I don't see how that can call `std::map::lowerbound( )` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A big objection to implementing `std::find` searching for a key on `std::map` as a non-member function is that doing so would prevent you from implementing the current version of `std::find`, which searches for a key-value pair.

Being an associative container, `std::map` contains key-value pairs. Non-member `std::find` is defined for all containers as a function that searches for an item in the container, which must be a key-value pair for `std::map`; using `std::find` to look up an item by its key would be inconsistent.

Obviously, one could implement `std::find_by_key` function applicable only to maps, but such function would always have a specialization based on the type of map. This provides no improvement in the API design over adding a member-function.

Comment: On your first point, surely `find(map.begin(), map.end(), map::value_type)` and `find(map.begin(), map.end(), map::mapped_type)` are not going to collide, and would just overload.

Comment: @KazDragon: The third argument to the generic `std::find` is independently deduced. That means for  `std::map<std::string, int>`, you get different overloads for `find(..., "Foo")` and `find(..., "Foo"s)`. Only the latter would work. The former selects the generic overload, even though there's a conversion from `char[4]` to `std::string`.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

> My colleague pointed out that it would be possible to implement `find` the same way as a non-member function using `map.lower_bound`.

This would lead to inconsistency across different types of maps. For instance, you cannot implement a free function `find` using the `lower_bound` member function for `std::unordered_map`, since there is no such member function (same for `google::dense_hash_map` etc.). Efficient `find` for `unordered_map` needs access to class internals and needs to know its implementation details. Then, you would end up with `map` not having `find` member function and `unordered_map` having one. This would make hard to write a generic code that would allow user to choose between different types of maps, such as:

```
template <class map_type>
void (const map_type & map) {
   // use std::find or map.find here ???
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` has a member find because `map::operator[]` and `map::at` don't cover all the use cases for looking up by key.

`operator[]` requires the `mapped_type` be *DefaultConstructible*, and modifies the size of the map if it fails to find.

`at` throws if it fails to find.

`find` doesn't have the restriction of `operator[]`, and neither modifies nor throws if it fails to find.

Comment: I thank you for taking the time to respond, but I believe you have missed the direction of my question.   It's not about whether there is a need for a special find function, it's about whether it is a member or non-member.